# How low can a VCO step up and down frequencies?

Tags: oscillator, voltage

So I am a hobbyist and I have in mind, a project I am working on and I need to sweep in a frequency range of 500 MHz with a step of 500Hz, and if my calculation is correct, this is equal to 1000000 step thats means that I need a VCO (voltage controlled oscillator) capable of 500Hz/x.ųv.
Can a VCO achieve that?

Comment: Please explain the units "Hz/x.uv".

Comment: @WA9ZZZ vco s are rated Hz/V for example 2MHz/V but am sure that it doesnt step by 1 volt so let stick on our example 2MHz/V = 2KHz/mV means each 1mV step 2KHz is increased for 5mV 10KHz .... so can VCO's step by microvolt for 500 Hz.

Comment: A VCO is an analog device.  There is no minimum step size.  Presumably, it will be a component of a PLL which will determine minimum step size.

Comment: @WA9ZZZ so what they do mean by 10MHz/V  ?

Comment: A micro-controller could drive a DAC, the output of which could control the VCO.  This would require a million steps or about 20 bits resolution for the DAC.  I don't know if that is possible.  Probably not the best approach to the problem.  A PLL can be controlled by a uC.

Comment: @Tintin  10MHz/V means that a change of 1volt on the control line changes the frequency by 10 MHz.  Are you looking at a specific part?

Comment: @Tintin  The VCO itself does not have steps.  The frequency output varies continuously over its range as the control voltage is varied.  Precision of the setting may be limited by noise in the circuit.  Any step size in the VCO output would be determined by its control circuit (e.g. PLL), not the VCO.

Comment: @Tintin, no. It’s an analog device that doesn’t have steps. That’s why I’m asking what you’re really trying to do, your questions about your attempted solution to your undisclosed problem make no sense.

Comment: @Tintin it doesn't make sense to webmarc, WA9ZZZ, me… And you already got your answer in multiple comments there, now that you clarified what you meant: it's an analog thing, it has no stepping behaviour, you're limited by noise.

Comment: Wrote a final answer on this.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Amateur Radio, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](/help/locked-posts). If, for some reason, you need the post deleted, you can raise an "In need of moderator intervention" flag, and a moderator can address your concerns.

Comment: @Jesse am not but when moderators became biased to some members it just ridiculous‍♂️

Comment: @Tintin This is not the correct way to voice your concerns. The correct way would either be to post on [Meta] to get feedback from the community or use the [Contact](https://ham.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the very bottom of the page to get in contact with a Stack Exchange community manager.

Comment: @Jesse i will proced to that if this persist 

Answer (score 3):

> How low can a VCO step up and down frequencies?

It can't. A VCO is an oscillator, not a mixer with an oscillator.

The numbers in your question make no sense either, sadly, nor does the unit "Hz/xµv".

**Update** after clarification that with "step up and down" the asker meant to ask for the *resolution limits* of a VCO, we can explicitly state that (as discussed in the comments):

A VCO is an analog device. Analog devices don't have "steps"¹! So, the question sadly makes no sense, in this sense, either.

You're only limited by your ability to control the VCO exactly – which will depend on how your control of the VCO looks. **So, that's not a property of your VCO, but of your VCO + controller!** 
 We therefore can't tell you that; you don't tell us whether it's open-loop or closed-loop, whether it's time-continuous or time-discrete, value-continuous or value-discrete, what noise this control scheme has, and if it's closed-loop, what the bandwidths are, how fast you need to achieve what level of accuracy in frequency, by what specific measure you want to bound your frequency error (the latter one is an especially important question, because defining what *frequency*  means for something that oscillates at intentionally changing rates is far from trivial but important for your question).

---

¹ quantum limits aside. In this context, we're not even close to working at the quantum level, so you can ignore that!

---

## Addressing the Elephant in the Room

Note that your question sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you ask about "X"; a property of a device that it doesn't have. But you don't ask that because you need to know that property, you ask that because you *think* it's the answer to some other question "Y"! Sadly, you forget to ask the other question "Y", which might actually *have* a sensible, useful (to you!) answer, unlike "X", which is really just a very confused question.

For example: sweeping an oscillator across 500 MHz in steps of 500 Hz? That makes very very little sense, unless you're building a [spectrum analyzer](https://www.aaatesters.com/Communications/Cellular_Networks/Anritsu_Rohde_Schwarz_WillTek_HP_BK_Precision_Agilent_Spectrum_Analyzers.html), and at that, an expensive one (read: price > new car).
I'm almost certain that's not what you want to build – you're still chasing the GNSS receiver, aren't you? You would never build a discrete frequency-stepping device for that, it just makes no sense, as satellites themselves fly around you, and thus exhibit Doppler shifts that are continuous, not discrete in nature, and need to be corrected for successful reception, anyways. And you can't do that by adjusting the frequency of your oscillator, because you need to do that with different corrections for multiple satellites that are flying in different directions, transmitting at the same time at the same frequencies. On the analog side, you need to build a multi-channel receiver, each channel tuned to its own GNSS band, that operate continuously on each channel without retuning. You then need digitize and to add correlator banks to each of these channels. This directly arises from how GNSS systems are built, and there's really copious amounts of literature on how to build GNSS receivers, whitepapers from companies that actually build receiver ICs.

You're, however, not approaching this from a "oh how can this be done? What components do I need? How can I logically structure my problem" perspective. You're doing what I'l call *conclusion-jumping based development*. You see a device, and think it solves your problem, try to read into what it does, don't even understand the basic terminology, quickly jump to conclusions, then build a totally wrong mental model of things. **That is understandable,** given that the things you need to learn to understand how any of this works involve literal years of learning math and physics, and you probably don't have that time. You very clearly don't have the background (e.g. having recently studied physics, or being an engineer in a math-adjacent field) to catch up on this quickly. You're a hobbyist that wants to see results without learning the basics. *That, however, is not going to work out for you.*

This approach has taken you days to come up with, bearing little to show, and us hours to correct.
It's not a wise investment of our time, and especially not of *your* time! That's why this answer is the last interaction you'll see with me until you start learning basics before trying to build something that does anything across 500 MHz, or at GHz frequencies, or involving RF circuitry. It's just that you try to skip a year of learning and hope that the right ideas just fall into your lap, and the rest of the world to work like you think. Not going to work, sorry.

Comment: we've conversed with each other for less than three weeks… goodbye. It's a bit sad that you don't seem to understand how much advice the others and me are giving :(

Comment: Whoever repeatedly proposes these redactions of this answer that removes 95% of the answer, and all the important parts: please stop doing that.